# How can I use yard doc in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, yard

When I add a new index page in activeadmin, I write some code like this:

```
# A default activeadmin page for yard overview
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end

  filter :email

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

In fact the activeadmin had create some view and controller, and I want to display some document  info in yard server, but the yarddoc ignore this file.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not write documentation because Active Admin is [Domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). Write good comments I do not see any other way.